# ScrollView autolayout in storyboard

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, scrollview, constraints

I'm trying to make app with scrollView in storyboard. Make constraints like this:
[image]

But it shows warning and offer to make `width = 0`.

[image: https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AADEdjcLyLNhpJk_kj1s5uWh-2qjRNhdcvQ-H9RL1qBLjg/12/189269726/png/1024x768/3/1418914800/0/2/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2010.45.34.png/CN6NoFogASgB/5LtCl851OXncmfwBArtYnHfIGKkFlk7Wz1lwYDZck-k]

I don't understand why. Are this constraints incorrect?

Comment: I figured out what is the problem with this simple views. Trying to make readable answer here.

Answer (score -1):

You should add missing constraints which should resolve layout issues and add missing constraints if it needed.

Answer (score -1):

Your ContentView is missing a `width` constraint. So at runtime, it will horizontally collapse since there is nothing to prevent it.

By default, your views tries to take the tiniest place possible, until you put constraints.

It also misses a constraint from the bottom of the ContentView to the bottom of the scrollView. Your scrollView can't guess how hight your content is until you put that last vertical constraint.

---

Your scrollview must have a top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints of its children views, in case the scroll content size is different from the children sizes.

Comment: It does not need constraint from bottom of contentview to scrollview's bottom because contentview has height constraint.

Comment: Also width constraint is not needed here because of horizontal space constraints.

Comment: Scroll view size is different from scroll view's content size. IB needs constraints outside of the scroll view to define the size and position from its parent, but the size of the content to be scrolled still needs to be defined with constraints. ContentView edges attached to the parent scrollview edges doesn't mean it will match the size of the parent scroll view. That's why it shows the warning `Expected: width=0`.

Comment: If you want your content to be the same width as your scroll view, add a _equals width_ constraint **coupled** with your existing horizontal spaces.